# Python while loop never stops even though it should

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop, infinite-loop

I've been going through some exercises from a book on algorithms (with an emphasis on Python), and I get strange behavior when I try to solve a certain problem.  The exercise is fairly straightforward and the goal is to generate a random integer `k` from `range(n)`, and then to locate this number through a sequence of "yes / no" questions.  The following code works as long as `n` isn't too large, but when it is I get an infinite loop.  But this shouldn't happen because in the worst case `step_size` will eventually equal one and `position` will crawl towards the value of `k` until `position == k`.

When I print both `step_size` and `position` it seems that `position` isn't updating when it gets too large, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the value getting approximated and truncated (this is why I tried to explicitly cast it as long, which may not in fact be doing anything).  Certain minor parts of the code are unnecessary, but I wanted to have it work for general `n`.  Any ideas as to what's going on (you will probably have to increase `n` to get the behavior I'm talking about)?

```
from random import randrange
from math import ceil

n = 10**15
k = randrange(n)

success = False
step_size = ceil(n / 2.0)
position = long(ceil(n / 2.0))

print(k)

while success == False:
    if position == k:
        success = True
        print(str(int(position)) + ' is the value of k.')
    elif k < position:
        step_size = ceil(step_size / 2.0)
        position -= step_size
        print(step_size, position)
    else:
        step_size = ceil(step_size / 2.0)
        position += step_size
        print(step_size, position)
```

Comment: What's the value of `k` when your program goes into an infinite loop?

Comment: are you sure you are getting an infinite loop and it's not just slow? I just copy pasted your code and ran it and it completed for me.

Comment: In Python 3 (after changing `long()` to `int()`) it works for me even with 10**200. Maybe there is some problem with how Python 2 handled big ints?

Comment: Just ran with `n = 10**20` and it repeats `k = 38680779789840615714`, `step_size = 1` and `position = 3.868077978984061e19` forever.

Comment: When adding 1.0 to your number 3.868977978984061e19, you are basically adding 0 as it doesn't have the needed precision. If I'm not mistaken you could even add a 1000 to it, and still see no change. :-)  see difference to the value of k, which has the last digits of 5714...

Comment: TO get from position=3+ to the size of k in increments of one will take a long time especially since you cut step_size in half each time.  Note that when using floats, position == k may never happen.  You should use a range, i.e. for -.0001 to .0001 difference,  if abs(position - k) < .0001, or whatever cut off you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use  `position += long(step_size)` and  `position -= long(step_size)`

```
  if position == k:
        success = True
        print(str((position)) + ' is the value of k.')
    elif k < position:
        step_size = ceil(step_size / 2.0)
        position -= long(step_size)
        print(step_size, position,k)
    else:
        step_size = ceil(step_size / 2.0)
        position += long(step_size)
        print(step_size, position)
```

If you don't `position` will be a float not a long.

With the change for `n = 10 ** 200` we get a value of:

```
11008769984569663730780658772914869218303604494435631537943840906720756507580926318660187453313745419228469341648307070867052432521026422402953409000922062458195678772749579263632191432518529106302726
11008769984569663730780658772914869218303604494435631537943840906720756507580926318660187453313745419228469341648307070867052432521026422402953409000922062458195678772749579263632191432518529106302726 is the value of k.
```

Comment: This should also circumvent the floating point precision problem

Comment: @holroy, exactly,  it cover both cases

Comment: Excellent, this works.  In the code I had, was the issue Python converting `position` to a float in order to do the addition / subtraction, and then losing precision?

Comment: @dsaxton,  exactly, you were fine up to a point but then you lost precision, you would either need longs or to use something like  `if abs(position - k) <= sys.float_info.min:`

Answer (score 2):

You're running into precision problems. Make sure your values are always represented as integers (not as floats). Python integers have arbitrary precision but floating point numbers don't.